# How to set the output parameters in camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am making a camera application which has :

1. A spinner that shows all supported resolutions to the user.
2. The selected resolution can be applied to the camera and the output image will be of the same resolution as selected.

So my approach till now has been:

a. I am adding this array to the spinner:

```
Sizes[] sizes = configurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
```

b. Then I let the user select from the spinner and I convert the selected option to two ints.

Till here it's cake walk, but from here on I do not understand how to apply these (width and height) to the camera to get an output of the image the same as that selected by the user.

I looked into using `OutputConfiguration()` but none of it's variants had a way to include both the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), which creates an ImageReader to receive JPEG images from a camera, to see how to set up a capture session with a preview and a callback to receive JPEG images.

You can just replace the JPEG format with YUV_420_888 in the ImageReader constructor, and the size with the value chosen by the user.